# How do i remove milliseconds

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I am using tsql to print time only. I end up getting the milliseconds portion. for eg

```
CONVERT(TIME, entrytime,20) as entrytime
```

this gives me

```
16:00:07.0000000
```

how can I get rid of the .0000000

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm sure there must be a better solution , but for now I can only think this solution:

```
SELECT CONVERT(char(8), GETDATE(), 108) AS time_without_milliseconds
```

Another combination:

```
SELECT CONVERT(TIME(0),GETDATE()) AS time_without_milliseconds
```

I hope will be useful for you.

Comment: I got a error 
Msg 9807, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
The input character string does not follow style 108, either change the input character string or use a different style.

Comment: @junkone now the code gets time with format **hh:mi:ss**

Comment: thanks it worked and I added a variation as I only wanted the time part.
substring(CONVERT(varchar, entrytime,108),11,10) as entrytime. now I got  16:00:07

Comment: @junkone its so strange this code should return only the time, maybe this will be useful:
**SELECT convert(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 108)**
or
**SELECT CONVERT(TIME(0),GETDATE()) AS newTime**

Comment: [Please don't advocate `varchar` without length](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx).

Comment: No worries. Style 108 can be `char(8)` though, instead of `varchar(10)`, if you're pedantic like me.

Comment: @AaronBertrand no problem, maybe this answer will be helpful to others, you say something like this **SELECT CONVERT(char(8), GETDATE(), 108)**?

Comment: Right, `char(8)` makes more sense to me than `varchar(10)`, since style 108 will always return exactly 8 characters.

Answer (score 4):

one more option

```
select format(getdate(),'hh:m:ss')---from 2012
```